# Multiplos inserts com JS (funciona no browser mas no app gerado pelo phonegap build não)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, phonegap-buillder, const

Atualizando pela solução indicação do @Sveen, em trocar `var` por `const`, porém funcionou apenas no browser, no app ele continua replicando apenas um valor:

```
for (var i in dados.valor) {
const query = "INSERT INTO teste ...";    
localDB.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql(query);
});
}
```

Esse é o trecho com os dados JSON a serem importados:

```
var dados = { "valor": [ 
        {'cod': 72214600, 'rep_img': '', 'descricao': 'Chave phillips 1/4\" x 6\" VONDER', 'aplic': 'Indicada para fixar e soltar parafusos com fenda cruzada/phillips', 'destaque': 'Produzida em aço cromo vanádio\, proporcionando maior resistência e durabilidade. Possui acabamento niquelado que confere maior resistência contra oxidação/corrosão. Conta com ponta magnetizada que facilita tanto a colocação quanto a retirada de parafusos em locais de difícil acesso\, além de cabo anatômico em polipropileno que garante maior conforto para o operador.', 'unid': 'PC', 'categoria': 'manuais', 'emb_cont': '1 Chave phillips', 'emb_tp': 'Sem Embalagem', 'emb_mst': 144.00, 'emb_sub': 6.00, 'emb_unit': 1.00, 'caract': 'Medida/Número da ponta da chave da chave Phillips: Nº2 - 1/4\" @ Comprimento da haste da chave: 6\" - 152 mm @ Material da haste da chave: Aço cromo vanádio @ Acabamento da haste da chave: Niquelado @ Material do cabo da chave: Polipropileno @ Cor do cabo da chave: Amarelo'},

        {'cod': 2372214600, 'rep_img': '', 'descricao': 'Chave phillips 1/4\" x 6\" VONDER', 'aplic': 'Indicada para fixar e soltar parafusos com fenda cruzada/phillips', 'destaque': 'Produzida em aço cromo vanádio\, proporcionando maior resistência e durabilidade. Possui acabamento niquelado que confere maior resistência contra oxidação/corrosão. Conta com ponta magnetizada que facilita tanto a colocação quanto a retirada de parafusos em locais de difícil acesso\, além de cabo anatômico em polipropileno que garante maior conforto para o operador.', 'unid': 'PC', 'categoria': 'manuais', 'emb_cont': '1 Chave phillips', 'emb_tp': 'Sem Embalagem', 'emb_mst': 144.00, 'emb_sub': 6.00, 'emb_unit': 1.00, 'caract': 'Medida/Número da ponta da chave da chave Phillips: Nº2 - 1/4\" @ Comprimento da haste da chave: 6\" - 152 mm @ Material da haste da chave: Aço cromo vanádio @ Acabamento da haste da chave: Niquelado @ Material do cabo da chave: Polipropileno @ Cor do cabo da chave: Amarelo'}
]};
```

**Código completo**

```
function insereDados(){

var dados = { "valor": [ 
{"cod":"72214600","rep_img":"","descricao":"Chave phillips 1\/4\" x 6\" VONDER","aplic":"Indicada para fixar e soltar parafusos com fenda cruzada\/phillips","destaque":"Produzida em a\u00e7o cromo van\u00e1dio&#44; proporcionando maior resist\u00eancia e durabilidade. Possui acabamento niquelado que confere maior resist\u00eancia contra oxida\u00e7\u00e3o\/corros\u00e3o. Conta com ponta magnetizada que facilita tanto a coloca\u00e7\u00e3o quanto a retirada de parafusos em locais de dif\u00edcil acesso&#44; al\u00e9m de cabo anat\u00f4mico em polipropileno que garante maior conforto para o operador.","unid":"PC","categoria":"manuais","emb_cont":"1 Chave phillips","emb_tp":"Sem Embalagem","emb_mst":"144.00","emb_sub":"6.00","emb_unit":"1.00","caract":"Medida\/N\u00famero da ponta da chave da chave Phillips: N\u00ba2 - 1\/4\" @ Comprimento da haste da chave: 6\" - 152 mm @ Material da haste da chave: A\u00e7o cromo van\u00e1dio @ Acabamento da haste da chave: Niquelado @ Material do cabo da chave: Polipropileno @ Cor do cabo da chave: Amarelo"},
{"cod":"3072700146","rep_img":"","descricao":"Chave phillips 1\/4\" x 6\" VONDER PLUS","aplic":"Indicada para fixar e soltar parafusos com fenda cruzada\/phillips","destaque":"Produzida em a\u00e7o cromo van\u00e1dio&#44; proporcionando maior resist\u00eancia e durabilidade. Possui acabamento niquelado que confere maior resist\u00eancia contra oxida\u00e7\u00e3o\/corros\u00e3o. Conta com ponta magnetizada que facilita tanto a coloca\u00e7\u00e3o quanto a retirada de parafusos em locais de dif\u00edcil acesso&#44; al\u00e9m de cabo anat\u00f4mico em polipropileno revestido com borracha termopl\u00e1stica que garante maior conforto para o operador.","unid":"PC","categoria":"manuais","emb_cont":"1 Chave phillips","emb_tp":"Sem Embalagem","emb_mst":"144.00","emb_sub":"6.00","emb_unit":"1.00","caract":"Medida\/N\u00famero da ponta da chave da chave Phillips: N\u00ba2 - 1\/4\" @ Comprimento da haste da chave: 6\" - 152 mm @ Material da haste da chave: A\u00e7o cromo van\u00e1dio @ Acabamento da haste da chave: Niquelado @ Material do cabo da chave: Polipropileno revestido com borracha termopl\u00e1stica @ Cor do cabo da chave: Preto e amarelo"},

]};



dados.valor.forEach(function(valor) {

var query = "INSERT INTO teste (cod, rep_img, descricao, aplic, destaque, unid, categoria, emb_cont, emb_tp, emb_mst, emb_sub, emb_unit, caract) VALUES ('" + valor[i].cod + "', '" + valor[i].rep_img + "', '" + valor[i].descricao + "', '" + valor[i].aplic + "', '" + valor[i].destaque + "', '" + valor[i].unid + "', '" + valor[i].categoria + "', '" + valor[i].emb_cont + "', '" + valor[i].emb_tp + "', '" + valor[i].emb_mst + "', '" + valor[i].emb_sub + "', '" + valor[i].emb_unit + "', '" + valor[i].caract + "');";


    localDB.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql(query);
});
});

}
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar um laço de repetição (ex: `for`, `while`, `forEach` etc).

Comment: Os valores vem de onde ? Utilize um `for` como já foi sugerido

Comment: Penso em colocar os valores direto no código como no trecho publicado, mas já busquei exemplos e não consegui, Isac ou Valdeir tem algum trecho simples apenas pra me basear? Os valores eu poderia pegar em JSON

Comment: Mudando um pouco de assunto, a sua maneira de conexão com o banco sofre riscos graves de ataque de Injection SQL, onde qualquer usuário tem controle total sobre o seu banco de dados. Inclusive ele pode deletar seu banco de dados ou inchar seu HD com dados no Mysql. https://www.tecmundo.com.br/tecmundo-explica/113195-sql-injection-saiba-tudo-ataque-simples-devastador.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explicação**

Sempre que você executa um loop, o valor da variável **query** é alterado (antes mesmo de ser executada), assim, quando o primeiro transaction for executado ele pegara o valor que já foi alterado diversas vezes.

**Solução 1**

Tente usar o modificador `const` em vez de `var` para variável **query**, para evitar que o oncomplete do transaction pegue sempre o último valor do loop. O resto pode continuar exatamente igual.

```
for (var i in dados.valor) {
    const query = "INSERT INTO teste ...";    
    localDB.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql(query);
    });
}
```

**Solução 2**

Se não funcionar, *dependendo da versão do Javsacript*, **outra solução** é utilizar o [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), assim você não corre o risco de reutilizar a mesma variável, pois cada dado estará em uma instância diferente

```
dados.valor.forEach(function(valor) {
   var query = "INSERT INTO teste (...) VALUES ('" + valor.cod + "', '" + valor.rep_img + "', '" + valor.descricao + "', '" + valor.aplic + "', '" + valor.destaque + "', '" + valor.unid + "', '" + valor.categoria + "', '" + valor.emb_cont + "', '" + valor.emb_tp + "', '" + valor.emb_mst + "', '" + valor.emb_sub + "', '" + valor.emb_unit + "', '" + valor.caract + "');";
    localDB.transaction(function(transaction){
        transaction.executeSql(query);
    });
});
```

lembrando que `valor` do forEach é um array contendo os dados a serem inseridos, o mesmo que `dados.valor[i]` no script anterior.

Comment: Perdão, na verdade ele deu certo no browser, porém no android ele continua pegando apenas um valor e replicando, mas dessa vez é o primeiro.

Comment: Ok vou colocar outra solução

Comment: Isso acontece porque o browser e o dispositivo móvel trabalham com versões diferentes

Comment: ok, vou testar e posto o resultado na sequencia... obrigado de novo

Comment: Obrigado pela força @Sveen mas não consegui entender onde vai const query = "INSERT...

Comment: alterei, fica no mesmo local

Comment: Alterei sua resposta e incluí meu código, ele não está fazendo as inserções, os dados do Array ficam como valor[i]?

Comment: @Skriza eu rejeitei sua edição na resposta pois ela pode alterar a intenção do autor da respota. Sugiro que ao invés de alterar a resposta você edite sua própria pergunta afim de incluir o código que quer mostrar.

Comment: Não @Skriza, cada valor fica como: {'cod': 72214600, 'rep_img': '', 'descricao': ... Amarelo'}, por exemplo

Comment: Não sei se era isso, postei o código completo na minha pergunta, não está realizando a inserção... nem no browser e nem no app

Comment: Inclui exemplo do uso do foreach na query.

Comment: @Sveen, cara... deu certo, me manda teu endereço que te mando uma cx de cerveja... muito obrigado pela ajuda, salvou minha vida!!

Comment: Foi nada, qualquer dúvida é só chamar